# 2 identical sites on nginx, but handling www prefix differently

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

I have 2 sites running on nginx (php wordpress).

For some reason redirects are working differently, although they both have the same vhost setup.

```
domain1.com redirects to www.domain1.com
www.domain1.com stays at www.domain1.com
```

domain2 seems to be acting strainge:

```
domain2.com stays at domain2.com
www.domain2.com redirects to domain2.com
```

What could be the issue?

both vhosts have this:

```
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com
server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com
```

**What I want is for both domains to redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com**

Comment: Will need your configuration file to tell, right now you're asking people to make random guesses.

Comment: We'll also need to know what code (if any) you've got running within those sites, as code can also generate redirects.

Comment: Also post the output of `wget --spider -qS http://{,www.}domain{1,2}.com/`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's most likely that wordpress is configured differently and is handling the rewrites in one case.

You can configure nginx to always redirect with something like:

```
if ($host ~* ^domain\.com) {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```